# Select records from XML string in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the below XML and want to select all the `allergenID` records

```
 DECLARE @Request XML

 SET @Request = '
<ProductAllergen>
<!---Gluten (Barley)-->
<Allergen>
  <AllergenID>1</AllergenID>
  <AllergenStatusID>1</AllergenStatusID>
</Allergen>
<!---Gluten (Wheat)-->
<Allergen>
  <AllergenID>2</AllergenID>
  <AllergenStatusID>1</AllergenStatusID>
</Allergen>
<!---Gluten (Rye)-->
<Allergen>
  <AllergenID>3</AllergenID>
  <AllergenStatusID>1</AllergenStatusID>
</Allergen>
<!---Eggs-->
<Allergen>
  <AllergenID>4</AllergenID>
  <AllergenStatusID>1</AllergenStatusID>
</Allergen>
 </ProductAllergen>
```

Currently this code gives me the first allergen record. (taking out the [1] didn't work)

```
SELECT  @Request.value('(//AllergenStatusID)[1]','int')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it work for me,

```
select xD.value('AllergenID[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') Productid 
from @Request.nodes('/ProductAllergen/Allergen') AS xm(xD)
```